# Tkinter string in a font measures differently than same in Text widget as string grows

Tags: python, text, tkinter, frame, measurement

The Text object holding a string (in a specified  font) seems to give inconsistent results depending on the length of the string.  For example:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFont
root=Tk()
t_Font = tkFont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=12, weight='bold')
t_text='New.'
t_frame = Frame(root, bd=0, height=10, width=t_Font.measure(t_text))
t = Text(master=t_frame, height=1, width=len(t_text), bd=1, font=t_Font, padx=0)
print '\n\nMeasured:', t_Font.measure(t_text), 'Frame req:', \
      t_frame.winfo_reqwidth(), 'As Text:', t.winfo_reqwidth()
```

`Measured: 38 Frame req: 38 As Text: 38`

```
t_text='New title.'
t_frame = Frame(root, bd=0, height=10, width=t_Font.measure(t_text))
t = Text(master=t_frame, height=1, width=len(t_text), bd=1, font=t_Font, padx=0)
print '\n\nMeasured:', t_Font.measure(t_text), 'Frame req:', \
      t_frame.winfo_reqwidth(), 'As Text:', t.winfo_reqwidth()
```

`Measured: 69 Frame req: 69 As Text: 92`

The additional 6 characters increased the measured size and frame size by 31 pixels, but the Text object has increased by 54.

**What causes this?**

Answer (score 5):

I realize its been 7 months, but wanted to answer this for anyone that ends up here like I did.

**TL;DR:** If you were using a fixed-width font, then it would have been a match (e.g. "Courier New").  But Helvetica is a proportional font, so its characters are not all the same width.

The `tkFont.measure()` and `Frame.winfo_reqwidth()` are both using the actual size for those strings of text in that font/weight/size, because their widths are specified in pixels.

The `Text` widget on the other hand has its width specified in characters.

So it's taking the number of characters each time and trying to guess for that font/weight/size how big to make the widget to handle them - but not the exact characters you're using.  It uses the zero character, `"0"`, as its average character size.

If you change your second set of `t_text`, `t_frame`, and `t` to `t_text2`, `t_frame2`, and `t2`, then `pack()` everything and start `root.mainloop()`, you can play around with the 2 widgets created.  The first one with `"New."` typed in doesn't even show the `"."` because the created field is slightly too small, while the second widget shows `"New title."` with extra spaces left.  Now if you delete those and enter `"0000"` for the first widget, and `"0000000000"` for the second, you'll see the widgets filled up exactly.

I found this through reading the Tcl/Tk docs for `text -width` on the [text manual page](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/text.htm#M21)  for Tk Built-In Commands.